# how to get a substring from a string in bash

Tags: bash

i have a problem with hash

i have to take a substring to a string from a specific char

for example if i have

```
"adgj    fghsjekoe     ===   / gghhj"
```

i have to take the string from "/", in this case

```
"/ gghhj"
```

but i don't know the real position, i know only that i have to take from `"/"`

which command can i use ? i have to use c`u`t? but i don't know what option to use. i need a command that can cut the string from `"/"` to the end of string.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
echo 'adgj fghsjekoe === / gghhj' | sed 's|.*/|/|'
```

Output:

```
/ gghhj
```

Comment: `.*` is greedy, watch out for input that has more `/`. For example: `foo/shouldbehere/bar`.

Comment: So basically `[^/]*` instead of `.*` (that's how I understood the question).

Comment: @PesaThe: If the problem should arise, this would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible `sed` solution:

```
$ echo "foo/bar" | sed 's#[^/]*##'
/bar
```

If you have the string in a variable, you can also use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) with [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) enabled. The advantage of parameter expansion is that it's handled by `bash`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob        #enables extglob
$ var="foo/bar"
$ echo "${var##*([^/])}"
/bar
```

```
$ echo "${var/*([^\/])}"  #another possible expansion
/bar
```

---

If there is no `/` in the input, all solutions will print nothing (I expect that is the desired behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You could use shell's internal facility itself by parameter expansion doing following.

```
val="adgj fghsjekoe === / gghhj"  ##Taking your string into a variable called val here.
echo ${val#*= }  ##Removing the value till `= ` by parameter expansion here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
/ gghhj
```

Comment: I suggest: `echo "/${val#*/}"`

Answer (score 0):

For such simple thing, I really think `sed` is overkill, there is a dedicated `cut` command :

```
echo "your string /..." | cut -d '/' -f 2
```

The `-d` argument specifies which character you use to cut the string, in our case, you want to cut at `/`. The `-f` argument specifies which field you want, starting from 1. Notice that you can do fancy things like `-f 2-` (i.e. fields 2 and followings), etc..

Answer (score 0):

You are using bash, so you have *parameter expansion with substring replacement* available. This uses the shell itself and avoids spawning an additional subshell calling a utility, e.g.

```
$ var="adgj    fghsjekoe     ===   / gghhj"
$ echo "${var/*\//\/}"
/ gghhj
```

The substring replacement has the form `${var/find/replace}` for a single replacement of `find` with `replace` and `${var//find/replace}` to replace all occurrences of `find` with `replace`.

(**note:** above the actual `/` to find and replace is escaped, e.g. `\/` to specify it as a literal `'/'` instead of part of the parameter expansion form)

You can also use *parameter expansion with substring removal* in your case. (although you need to foresight to prefix the result with the `'/'` you will be removing). For example to trim a string from the *left* up to a particular character (the forward slash here), you can use `${var#*/}`. That however would leave you with just `" gghhj"`, but that is handled simply by prefixing the expansion with an additional `/` to take the place of the one you remove, e.g.

```
$ var="adgj    fghsjekoe     ===   / gghhj"
$ echo "/${var#*\/}"
/ gghhj
```

(**note:** here, there is no need to escape the `'/'` as there is no `/` in the *substring removal* form)